# Class Cast Exception in HandlerMethod Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to create custom annotation that modify request. so create this annotation.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
 boolean test() default true;
}
```

and also MyInceptor class that extend from HandlerInterceptorAdapter. now in preHndler method in this class i want to cast handler to HandlerMethod. but an exception appear.for this exception i put a condition "if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod)" but handler not cast to handler method atall.
How hanle this problem?

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
    MyAnnotation myAnnotation = null;
    if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
        HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod ) handler;
       //other 
    }
}
```

Update 
this exception occur.

```
       java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod
```

Comment: Post a complete stack trace and identify the statement that throws the exception.